# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup api.xxxx.xx on 172.20.0.1:53: no such host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, istio

I have kubernetes cluster on AWS. Added nameserver provided by route53. It was working fine till date. Currently its not working. 
How to fix this error. 
Tried to add host manually to /etc/hosts but still not working

Comment: Let's check the DNS first Do you get an IP address reply when you ping the kubernetes name?